# In C# specify access modifier for a method is equivalent to get and set

Tags: c#

I'm learning for the Microsoft Exam 70-483. In this exercise the correct answers are A and F. In my opinion E is correct too. I think E is fully equivalent to A + F. Is it true?

**Question:**
You are creating a class named `Employee`. The class exposes a string property named `EmployeeType`. The following code segment defines the `Employee` class. (Line numbers are included for reference only.)

```
01 public class Employee
02 {
03     internal string EmployeeType
04     {
05         get;
06         set;
07     }
08 }
```

The `EmployeeType` property value must be accessed and modified only by code within the `Employee` class or within a class derived from the `Employee` class.You need to ensure that the implementation of the `EmployeeType` property meets the requirements. Which two actions should you perform? (Each correct answer represents part of the complete solution. Choose two.)

A. Replace line 05 with the following code segment: `protected get;`

B. Replace line 06 with the following code segment: `private set;`

C. Replace line 03 with the following code segment: `public string EmployeeType`

D. Replace line 05 with the following code segment: `private get;`

E. Replace line 03 with the following code segment: `protected string EmployeeType`

F. Replace line 06 with the following code segment: `protected set;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework!

Comment: You would do well to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

Comment: Since "_(Each correct answer represents part of the complete solution. Choose two.)_" then yeah E might be correct but you need to choose two. Choosing E and something else is `half correct` in this case and you won't get the full grade.

Comment: This is not homework, he is studying for the 70-483 Microsoft test

Comment: Disagree, the answers are already here, it's a question about... why...

Comment: A and F cannot be correct at the same time and they cannot be correct without modifying line 3 as well. E **does** work.

Comment: `(Each correct answer represents part of the complete solution. Choose two.)`  <--- **this is part of the question... read carefully....**

Comment: If we do A or F code will not compile because of `internal` access modifier. Doing both is worst

Comment: "The EmployeeType property value must be accessed and modified only by code within the Employee class or within a class derived from the Employee class." You cannot choose 2 answers to make this true.

Comment: ok, the fact i've to choose two exclude E to be correct.

Comment: @FelipeOriani 'Homework' is not a reason for a question to be offtopic. Very often homework questions *are* off topic, but it's not a reason by itself. This question is perfectly fine.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Is correct: If we make those two changes alone (A and F) then the code won't compile! The question is crap, IMO (that's the exam question, not the OP's question!). In fact, the only acceptable answer would have to be `E`, but the question doesn't allow us to give that answer.

Comment: If you forget about the declaration `internal`, the property will also be accessable by derived classes in other assemblies.

Comment: If you must choose two: do C first and then E :)

Comment: @Dennis_E I like the way you think ;)

Comment: @FelipeOriani "homework" is not a valid close reason. If a question stands on its own merit, it doesn't matter whether it's homework or not.

Comment: @Dennis_E, and let's hope the order matters for the "teacher" ;)

Comment: The 'correct' answer (with logic they use) is A & F but the question is incorrect

Comment: @Fabjan A & F won't compile....

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Oh yea it won't but still it is the 'correct' answer to an incorrect question. Because of words:  ' which *two* actions ...'

Comment: @Fabjan, As [Dennis_E said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616442/#comment66540126_39616442), the two actions required are C & E (in order :) )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There must be an error in your question. You can't choose 2 responses and answer the question. The only correct answer is E

1. You can't have an access modifier for both getter and setter (so A+F is wrong)
2. Access modifier on getter OR setter must be more restrictive than the property's access modifier. `protected` is not more restrictive than `internal`.

Comment: I agree - the question must have an error, because it is impossible to answer it if you must choose two changes.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is (if I am not mistaken) A and F but the error of course is there... To answer it correctly one need to understand that there is a mistake in a question.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in question. Requirements should be:

> The value must be accessed only by code within the Employee class or
> within a class derived from the Employee class. The value must be
> modified only by code within the Employee class.

and then the answer would be:

> Replace line 03 with the following code segment: protected string
> EmployeeType
>
> Replace line 06 with the following code segment: private set;

OP is confused because the question is from a braindump from **MS EXAM 70-483**, where questions and answers are not always correctly connected. This happens somewhat frequently, I'm not sure exactly the reason, but stuff like this is expected from bootleg copies. What I posted is the question that fits the answers, which would then be B and E.